# Is there a way the closed question on "protests against Amy Barrett" be opened again?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Is there a way this question : [Why are people protesting against Amy Barrett?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/59127/33033) can be re-written to make it "fact-based" and get it opened?

The first revision had some of my own opinions and then I removed it after someone had advised. I, myself was the fifth close voter because having received six downvotes and four close-votes I had realised something was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reopened it. I added the [summary-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summary-request) tag because you're asking about background information for protests against this specific nominee. As such, I think it's the scope is sufficiently narrowed down to get useful answers.